# How to filter multiple objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my array

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([
  { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 40},
  { id: 2, name: 'Jane', age: 50 },
]);
```

I used `filter` to search,

```
{arr.filter(product => product.name.includes(value)).map((row) => (
  <TableRow>
    <TableCell align="center">{row.id}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="center">{row.name}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="center">{row.age}</TableCell>
  </TableRow> 
))}
```

Now I can only search by `name`, I would like to search by both `name` or `age`.

Comment: Did you try adding that condition to the filter callback? This isn't unique to React at all, just basic JS.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hope this will help you

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    function Data() {
      const [arr, setArr] = useState([
        { id: 1, name: "John", age: 40 },
        { id: 2, name: "Jane", age: 50 },
      ]);
    
      const [userName, setName] = useState("");
      const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
    
      let filtered = arr.filter(
        (name) => name.name === userName || name.age === Number(age)
      );
    
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            placeholder="age"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setAge(e.target.value);
            }}
            value={age}
          />
          <input
            placeholder="name"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setName(e.target.value);
            }}
            value={userName}
          />
    
          {filtered.map((row) => (
            <>
              <h1>{row.id}</h1>
              <h1>{row.name}</h1>
              <h1>{row.age}</h1>
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the logical OR operator e.g.

```
let age = 40;
arr.filter(product => product.name.includes(value) || product.age == age)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const filteredArr = arr.filter(product => product.name.includes(value) || product.age === value);
{filteredArr.map((row) => (
 <TableRow>
    <TableCell align="center">{row.id}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="center">{row.name}</TableCell>
    <TableCell align="center">{row.age}</TableCell>
 </TableRow> 
))}
```